# Is there an alternative to .some in this statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have an if statement to check responses from a collector against a list in a .json file.

```
if(collected.content.toLowerCase() === some.check.yes)
```

I know the syntax is very wrong but is there some way to do this? Maybe an alternative command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I understand you want to do: there's a list of values in a JSON file, and you want to check whether the message contains at least one of them. If this is the case, then you can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
If you only want to check whether the message is one of the words in the list, you can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] // This should be the list from your JSON file

// This will be true if the message is one of the words on the list
let first = list.includes(collected.content.toLowerCase())

// This will be true if the message contains at least one word from the list
let second = list.some(el => collected.content.toLowerCase().includes(el))
```